# Like/Dislike system without authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, ip

I developped a Like/Dislike system on my website [WDMND.com](http://WDMND.com/).

I am using asp.net with C#.

My goal is to get the feeling of every visitor, even without authentication.

So, I limited the vote on every single control to 1 per IP.

I realised that two users of the same family can't share both their opinion, because they have the same IP :(

I tought myself "No problem! I'll just limit the votes with the MAC address :D". Unfortunatly it is not possible :P

I then had the idea of using cookies! The thing is... Some trolls will go like :

```
while (!timeToGoToBed)
{
   vote --;
   cookie.delete();
}
```

This is where I am in my reflection.. I don't really know what to do with it. Should I just keep it like this or is there a better way to do this?

**Is there a way to see a difference between two users (computers) with the same ip?**

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not figure out the average number on people in every household maybe using say US census data if applicable. So lets say there are 3 users on average that meet your demographic then allow 3 votes max per ip.

Comment: This website is made for a specific video game, maybe 5% of the users will have a brother playing the game too, I don't want the other 95% to be able to vote twice :P

Comment: You will notice that, after a vote, if you refresh the page, the thumb you clicked will keep its Hover state, because I know this IP vote what. So if his brother opens the website on another PC he will see and be able to change his brother's vote :P

Comment: Did you do any analytics to see how frequently this realy occurs. Do you track the time of the vote? Maybe at the time of the vote you provide them with some kinda of key. If the ip votes again perhaps have something popup and ask a question related to the key. Maybe consider a vote as new if it occurs several hours after the initial.

Comment: I just took a look at the site and perhaps if you create a timeline visualization that shows when the votes occured during the day. Kind of look google analytics. Could you use 3rd party tracking service? Is this site Canadian or Francais?

Comment: This website is visited frequetly by the same users, I don't want them to vote every 2 days. It didn't occur yet, but I know it will, not frequetly but it will

Comment: It is used by french canadians and french europeans

Comment: Some of the players I know have other members of their family playing

Comment: Maybe you could provide a user with a token that they use to vote and combine that with ip to get the unique information you are looking for,

Comment: Asking them to log in at this point would be easier :P

Comment: I am not saying a traditional user name and password just requiring a single token. To bad you can't integrate a profile system into the game directly. So if the first time the user enters the game you identify them by ip. Next time they visit you greet them saying do you wish to play under an existing or you a new user. You could tie their scores and progress that way.

Answer (score 2):

My advise - if you want the tractability that comes with authenticating users, but still have the convenience of letting anonymous users interact with your data, you will need to sacrifice somewhere.
I used to always look for ways I could get site interaction without users having to login, but still protect the site from abuse etc and I came to the conclusion that at some point there will be more pro's than con's in requiring users to sign-in. Amazon and Google require you sign-in to leave comments or vote.

If you think you users will not want to sign-in just limit it by IP address, you are thinking to deep about the downsides of that, remember you are allowing them to instantly interact with your site, anything more then they should sign-up. However I really suggest you prompt the user to sign-in, just allow sign-in with Google/Hotmail/Facebook etc. Most users have dummy account setup that they use for those things anyway. You would be surprised. Remember to that in some universities and internet cafe's, all the users share the same public IP address, so you might be isolating large amounts of users by only looking at their IP. Good luck

Comment: That's exactly the problem I was trying to tell, well said :P
I think I will let it like this, but when we log in, they'll be able to vote by login, not by IP. So there will be a possibility of 2 votes by user maximum, users with no login will be able to vote, and members of the same family/university/etc will be able to log in and vote!